# Move body background image

Tags: html, css, image, position

I am using this CSS to put an image into the `<body>`:

```
body {
  background: url('picture.png') no-repeat; 
  background-size: contain;
}
```

The image is displayed at the top of the browser window, but I need to place this image a few pixels from the top.

I've tried using `padding/margin-top: 20px;`, but it didn't help me, the image is still at the top of the browser window.

How can I move this background image for the `body` tag a few pixels down from the top?

Note: I need to have the picture in the body tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `background-position` instead.

```
body {
  background: url('picture.png') no-repeat; 
  background-position: 0 20px;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use css background-position property,

example

```
body {
  background: url('picture.png') no-repeat; 
  background-position: 0px 50px; /* This makes the image appear 50px from top */
  background-size: contain;
}
```